# External wired USB mouse not detecting

Tags: windows-10, laptop, mouse, acer-aspire

I am using ACER 5755g laptop, it had a mouse pad issues and then stopped working so I unplugged the cable from the mother board. Then I tried plugging my DELL N889 Wired mouse, but it is not detecting. I went to check on device manager all I can find is it is listed under human interface device as a USB input device. I am using Windows 10 OS. Thanks

Comment: Yes i did , While boot up the mouse optical sensor light turned on but once the windows 10 logo for loading comes it got turned off

Comment: What about other USB devices?

Comment: Ya i have checked My USB thumb drive detecting fine